# Font color not changing when choosing different theme in aptana studio 3.6

Tags: aptana, aptana3

so far I've used aptana build 3.4.

I recently installed Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044 on my new mac, and by default the theme is bright.

I tried changing the theme to be dark, but only the background colors seems to change. 
The font stay the same as before no matter what I do.

I change the theme via:

[image]

but the font color doesn't change, but stays like the default (light theme). and thus it looks weird:

[image]

Tried searching for solution for hours now but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello OmriToptix. Could you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I moved to Pycharm a while ago but I don't recall finding an answer to this issue back then.

Comment: Hey OmriToptix, The edit part of @Breaker222 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colors for PyDev editors via: **Preferences > PyDev > Editor**

...but unfortunatly I also have not found out, how to apply the color-themes.

---

edit: somebody came up with a solution to the python-editor theme problem, that worked for me :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075375/3313410