# Aptana Studio 3: How to apply themes to python editor

Tags: python, colors, themes, editor, aptana

How can I change the colors **with a theme(*)** in Aptana Studio 3 (3.6.0.201407100658 on Ubuntu) for python editors? For other editors (like for js-files or html-files) it works, as seen in the reference picture (left = python, right = js w/ "aptana-studio" theme):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyVLA.png]

So far I couldn't find any answers on the web to this problem.

*I have found out, that I can change the colors for a python editor in the preferences under *preferences > PyDev > Editor* , but this this is more like a workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Eclipse Market Place on Aptana Studio
From Eclipse Market Place install Eclipse Color theme Plugin
You will find out most of the popular themes after installing plugin.(In Aptana Studio -> Window->Preferences->Appearance->Color Theme). You can also install themes from [here](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) by importing themes.

To install Eclipse market place on Aptana Studio 3. go to the help tab->install new software then click on the availible sources link then add the kelper site. Back on the previous screen you should wait to see the kelper packages loading. Wait for it to finish loading and then find search for marketplace it should be listed under general tools. Then accept and market will be listed under the help tab

Comment: I installed the two plug ins. The described options appeared in the preferences and worked as intended :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Perfect solution so far. But small change is, in Aptana 3, look for "Color theme" inside, Windows-> Preferences-> General-> Appearance-> Color theme. Thank you for the solution @user12321.

Answer (score 0):

**My Problem:** Standard theme change in Aptana Studio 3 (Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Theme) resulted in background color change but awkward script color which either blended with background or provided visual work space discomfort.

**My Solution:** 
Open Aptana Studio 3 then navigate to the following:
Help->Install New Software->Click on expand button next to "Add" button->Choose Eclipse Kepler Update Site option-> Check the Eclipse Market Place install box and download the Market Place software.

Access the Eclipse Market Place: Help->Eclipse Market Place-> Search for Eclipse Color Theme Plug-In and follow download steps.

**!IMPORTANT!**: You must then navigate to: Window->Preference->Aptana Studio->Theme-> Check the box "Apply to all(non-Studio) editors". If you don't the Eclipse Color Theme Plug-In won't work properly (this is what I discovered when I tried other peoples solutions in this community).

Finally, navigate to Window->Preference->General->Appearance->Color Theme-> and choose your theme! (Obsidian is my favorite). Have fun!