# Theme change in Aptana Studio Issue (already downloaded Eclipse Market Place and Eclipse Color Theme Plug in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, themes, aptana

After following the instructions found in: [Aptana Studio 3: How to apply themes to python editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074933/aptana-studio-3-how-to-apply-themes-to-python-editor/28075375#28075375) I still can't change my theme.

In Aptana Studio 3 I go to Windows->Preferences->General->Color Theme and choose the appropriate theme but the background remains the standard white color. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have to navigate to Windows->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes and check the box at the bottom of the window 'Apply to all (non-Studio) editors'. Then having downloaded Eclipse Market Place and the Color Theme Plug-In you can change the theme (background & font) of your primary work space.